# Is it possible to not match an escaped FS character?

Tags: awk

For the data I'm processing, the field separation character is ':'. I was wondering if there's an FS value that can be set to allow allow fields to contain : by escaping it (':').

From where I've looked, I doesn't think it is possible with AWK's regular expressions set, but I figured I'd ask anyways.

Luckily it isn't necessary for my current project, just curious for future reference.

Comment: GNU awk and [FPAT](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html).

Comment: Replace the `:` that are not escaped with `perl`, sth like `perl -pe 's/(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*\K:/§/g'` and then use `§` as the `FS` for `awk`.